# The space of differential forms is a module over the space of forms

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, differential-forms

I've read a statement that the space of differential forms is a module over the space of forms $\bigoplus_{m=0}^n \Lambda^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Where $\Lambda^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of $m$-forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and here $m$-forms $\omega_p$ are differential $m$-forms $\omega$ evaluated at a point $p$. e.g. if $\omega=xy\,dx$ and $p=(1,2)$, then $\omega_p=2\,dx.$

What I'm having trouble to accept is the direct sum. The only operation I know between (differential) forms with different dimensions is the wedge product. But it is anti-commutative. The usual addition is meaningless between different dimensions. Like what is $dx+dx\wedge dy$? So I'm not sure $\bigoplus_{m=0}^n \Lambda^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is closed under addition.

Comment: One cannot add the elements, consider them as tuples. It's akin to when you consider $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R^2} \simeq \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @bounceback If the elements of the space of forms are of the form (1-form, 2-form, ..., n-form), and the elements of the space of differential forms are of the form (differential 1-form, ..., differnetial n-form), then how do we do the scalar multiplication? Thanks for the comment btw.

Comment: One can consider direct sums of any vector spaces.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Why are you distinguishing between 1-forms and differential 1-forms? To me these are the same. They are monsters that eat vector fields.

Comment: @bounceback that's from Michael Penn's lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyaWHQO-wSc&t=232s

Comment: Your title and first sentence make no sense. Space of differential forms where? The graded algebra you wrote down is a module over the ring of smooth functions on $\Bbb R^n$.